# getting output for only one key in a map reduce program

Tags: mapreduce

I am trying to write a Map Reduce program to do a join between two text files. The output that I get, is only for one of the keys. For example, if I have one file `R.txt` with data as

a4 b3
a3 b4

and another file `S.txt` with data as
b3 c3
b3 c1
b3 c2
b4 c4

I get the output

a4  c2
a4  c1
a4  c3

whereas if `R.txt` has
b4 c4

and `S.txt` has
a3 b4

the output is
a3 c4.

Here is my program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;     

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;  

public class RSJoin{
    public static class SMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{ 
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] words = value.toString().split(" ");
            context.write(new Text(words[0]), new Text("S\t"+words[1]));
            }
}
    public static class RMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{ 
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] words = value.toString().split(" ");
            context.write(new Text(words[1]), new Text("R\t"+words[0]));
            }
}

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (Text val : values) {
            String [] parts = val.toString().split("\t");
            String a=parts[0];
            if (a.equals("R")){
                for (Text val1 : values){
                String [] parts1=val1.toString().split("\t");
                String b=parts1[0];
                if (b.equals("S")){
                    context.write(new Text(parts[1]), new Text(parts1[1]));
                }
                }
            }
        }

  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job = new Job(conf, "ReduceJoin");
    job.setJarByClass(RSJoin.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,RMap.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,SMap.class);


    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: For the first example output should be a4 c2, a4 c1, a4 c3, a3 c4. The output I get is a4 c2, a4 c1, a4 c3. The join does not happen for b4 but happens only for b3. I expect the code to work just as a natural join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join logic assumes that the R value comes before the S value in the values list.  Only when you see an R do you then look for an S.  The inner for over the values Iterable begins where the outer for left off so if the S comes first your nine loop won't find it.

If you only have one R value for multiple S values, either do a secondary sort (adding "R" and "S" to the key, adding a partitioner and adding a grouping comparator - this is the right way) or have a variable to hold the R value once you find it, a list to hold S values until you find the R value (doesn't really scale well) and have a single iteration throughout the set of values.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the reducer code as below and got the expected output

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<String> listR = new ArrayList <String>();
    List<String> listS = new ArrayList <String>();
    for (Text val : values) {
        String [] parts = val.toString().split("\t");
        String a=parts[0];
        if (a.equals("R")){
            listR.add(parts[1]);    
        }
        else if (a.equals("S")){
            listS.add(parts[1]);
            }
        }
    for (String Temp: listR)
    {
        for (String Temp1: listS)
        {
            context.write(new Text(Temp), new Text(Temp1));
        }
    }

    }
```